# Why doesn't Professor X use Cerebro to locate Sabertooth or any of Magneto's henchmen?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men

I'm confused on one thing about the movie I just watched:

In the first **X-Men movie**, **Professor X** is unable to locate **Magneto** with **Cerebro**, thanks to the power of Magneto's helmet, but why doesn't he use it to locate **Sabretooth** or any of Magneto's other henchmen? the ones that are constantly around Magneto?

Comment: Good question! - but I just think it is one of the plethora of plot holes that range across this excellent but deeply inconsistent epic series of films. I mean why does he not sense that Mystique is creeping around the mansion pretending to be Bobby - he would not even need Cerebro for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, most of the time Sabertooth and Toad stayed at that place where Magneto lives. This house appears to be protected from Professor X's brainwaves. This is why we can see Magneto wandering in that house without his helmet. Here is the picture of him from the movie.

[image]

[image]

Perhaps this is the reason Professor X can't track them.

Another possibility is that he never needed to.

He first used Cerebro for finding Rogue. That's when he also went to railway station to save her. After that, Senator Kelly went to Xavier mansion. That's when Charles looked into his mind and found the base of Magneto. However, finding Magneto's place wasn't as important as destroying the machine that turns humans into mutants.

When Senator Kelly dies, Professor says,

> I am going to find her.

Here, he is going to find Rogue and that's how he can reach Magneto. However, he fell into coma because of Mystique's sabotage before he could locate Rogue.